‘ please minimize large stack variables’ error while running anchor build (Mac air M1)
I have encountered an error when compiling a Solana smart contract using Anchor build on a Mac M1, while it works fine on Linux Ubuntu.
➜  solana-auction git:(master) ✗ solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.8 (src:e2d34d37; feat:3469865029, client:SolanaLabs)
➜  solana-auction git:(master) ✗ anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.29.0
➜  solana-auction git:(master) ✗ sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     13.4
BuildVersion:       22F66
➜  solana-auction git:(master) ✗ anchor build
   Compiling syn v1.0.109
   Compiling libc v0.2.148
   Compiling serde v1.0.188
   Compiling generic-array v0.14.7
   Compiling syn v2.0.37
   Compiling subtle v2.5.0
   Compiling ahash v0.8.3
   Compiling either v1.9.0
   Compiling itertools v0.10.5
   Compiling getrandom v0.2.10
   Compiling hashbrown v0.13.2
   Compiling crypto-common v0.1.6
   Compiling block-buffer v0.10.4
   Compiling cpufeatures v0.2.9
   Compiling jobserver v0.1.26
   Compiling digest v0.10.7
   Compiling cc v1.0.83
   Compiling sha2 v0.10.8
   Compiling sha3 v0.10.8
   Compiling borsh-schema-derive-internal v0.9.3
   Compiling borsh-derive-internal v0.10.3
   Compiling borsh-derive-internal v0.9.3
   Compiling borsh-schema-derive-internal v0.10.3
   Compiling blake3 v1.5.0
   Compiling solana-program v1.16.14
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.188
   Compiling thiserror-impl v1.0.49
   Compiling solana-frozen-abi-macro v1.16.14
   Compiling bytemuck_derive v1.5.0
   Compiling solana-sdk-macro v1.16.14
   Compiling num-derive v0.3.3
   Compiling anchor-derive-space v0.28.0
   Compiling thiserror v1.0.49
   Compiling bytemuck v1.14.0
   Compiling bv v0.11.1
   Compiling serde_bytes v0.11.12
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.107
   Compiling bincode v1.3.3
   Compiling toml v0.5.11
   Compiling solana-frozen-abi v1.16.14
   Compiling anchor-syn v0.28.0
   Compiling proc-macro-crate v0.1.5
   Compiling borsh-derive v0.10.3
   Compiling borsh-derive v0.9.3
   Compiling borsh v0.9.3
   Compiling borsh v0.10.3
   Compiling anchor-attribute-event v0.28.0
   Compiling anchor-derive-accounts v0.28.0
   Compiling anchor-attribute-access-control v0.28.0
   Compiling anchor-attribute-program v0.28.0
   Compiling anchor-attribute-account v0.28.0
   Compiling anchor-attribute-error v0.28.0
   Compiling anchor-attribute-constant v0.28.0
Error: Function _ZN112_$LT$solana_program..instruction..InstructionError$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiEnumVisitor$GT$13visit_for_abi17hbd61cce4f3fa5190E Stack offset of 4608 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 512 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN108_$LT$solana_program..vote..state..CircBuf$LT$I$GT$$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiExample$GT$7example17h47aaa93a7f35b0f0E Stack offset of 4640 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 544 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
   Compiling anchor-lang v0.28.0
   Compiling auction v0.1.0 
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 37.55s
➜  solana-auction git:(master) ✗ 


https://github.com/danielbui12/solana-auction

The errors are due the dependency versions in the Cargo.toml file
Update from:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.28.0"
solana-program = "1.16.13"

To:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
solana-program = "1.18.8"

Then anchor build should run successfully.
You'll also need to make a few updates to that specific project to run locally.

Run anchor keys sync to update the program ID in declare_id.
Then update the hardcoded program address in the test file (you can also get the local program address by running anchor keys list)
Then update the wallet in Anchor.toml with wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"
Then update ./utils/secretKey.ts/ with "/path/to/your/.config/solana/id.json"

Now when you run anchor test, the test should run.
(The answer is referencing the project left as comment above)
Error itself seems to be related to: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/35003

I've faced the same issue where building program in Ubuntu working fine but not on M1 Mac.
Building program with docker fixed my problem. Steps to solve,

Install and start docker
Run the solana-test-validator -r in 2nd terminal
Run anchor build --verifiable https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/verifiable-builds
Run anchor deploy
Run anchor run test

My environment:

Anchor version - 0.29.0
Solana cli version - 1.17.17
Rustc version -  1.76.0

